# How can I stop an animation without to reset the spinning rotation in CSS (example explains it best)

Tags: css, animation, rotation, css-transforms

I have a little noobish CSS question If someone could share some free time to help. what I want to do is the div to stop and freeze at the position whenever I leave (hover off) my cursor, and not reset to his fixed starting position.

```
<script>

.rotatingDiv {
width: 50px;
height: 30px;
background-color: red;
margin: auto;
margin-top: 10rem;
cursor: pointer;
}

.rotatingDiv:hover {
animation: spin 4s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes spin {
0% {
 transform: rotate(0deg);
}
100% {
 transform: rotate(360deg);
}
}

</script>


<body>
<div class="rotatingDiv"> </div>
</body>
```

as seen on the example the div keeps reseting to the starting position which is 0deg (default) on mouse-out, so what I want to achieve is for the div to freeze at the exact degree whenever I leave my cursor (mouse out/ hover off) from the div.

Comment: This may be of help to you https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-play-state

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to stop css animation in current position on hover?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33237822/how-to-stop-css-animation-in-current-position-on-hover)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you wanted this thing it would be work

```css
.rotatingDiv {
    width: 50px;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: red;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 10rem;
    cursor: pointer;
    animation: spin 4s linear infinite;
    animation-play-state: paused;
    }

    .rotatingDiv:hover {
    animation: spin 4s linear infinite;
    }

    @keyframes spin {
    0% {
     transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
     transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
    }
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="rotatingDiv"> </div>
    </body>
```